# Will an object defined inside a C++ function be destroyed after it goes out of scope?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pointers, syntax, garbage-collection

I've defined an object inside a function:

```
SoundFXSystem* Engine::GetSystem(){
   SoundFXSystem system; // var defined inside a function
   sEngine->GetSystem(&system);
   return &system; // can I return the address of the var?
}
```

Is it legal to return the address of the var and use it later in the program? Will it go out of scope immediately as the function exits and be unavailable for use by the caller?

**Edit:** If I define the object as follows, will it be dynamically allocated?

```
SoundFXSystem* Engine::GetSystem(){
   SoundFXSystem* system = new SoundFXSystem(); // var defined inside a function
   sEngine->GetSystem(&system);
   return system; 
}
```

Comment: Never return the address of a non-static local variable. It is **undefined behavior** to dereference said-address one the scope in which it resides is left.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Returning local data from functions in C and C++ via pointer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127507/returning-local-data-from-functions-in-c-and-c-via-pointer)

Comment: **Every** object is destroyed when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Every `automatic storage duration object` has a lifespan that is linked to the scope. Static storage duration object on the other hand have a lifespan equivalent to the application and thus it will not be destroyed when scope is left.

Comment: Don't dynamically create it and return a pointer (return an object that will control its lifespan (smart pointer of some description)) or return by value or make it static thus extending its lifespan.

Comment: @LokiAstari - yes, but that obscures my point, which was about scopes. Execution never enters or leaves static scope, so it's off the point.

Comment: @PeteBecker: There is not such thing as static scope. You blatantly ignored a whole set of conditions and rather thus rather crudely made things worse. That is why I had to post a comment. Things are not destroyed when they go out of scope. Things are destroyed when their lifetime ends. Only automatic variables lifetimes end when they go out of scope (that leaves three other types of variable that you did not cover and static storage duration objects are common (and a good way to sole this particular problem ie declare `system` as a static member of the function )).

Comment: Yes, objects are destroyed when their lifetimes end. This question isn't about objects in general, but about objects **defined in functions**, and the lifetime of an object defined in a function ends when it goes out of scope. **Whenever** an object goes out of scope it gets destroyed, which is what I said to begin with. I really don't understand what you're so up in arms about.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the object is defined in the function's scope, so it goes out of scope when the function's scope ends. You need to either:

1. return it by value instead, or
2. allocate it dynamically, that is, using `new` or `std::make_shared`

If you allocate it using `new`, make sure somebody will know to `delete` it later. That's why it's preferred to return `std::unique_ptr` instead of raw pointers from allocating functions - it avoids possible memory leaks.

To return by value instead, you'd change your function as follows:

```
SoundFXSystem Engine::GetSystem(){
   SoundFXSystem system; // var defined inside a function
   sEngine->GetSystem(&system);
   return system;  //return var by value
}
```

Comment: You should also mention that it is because the object is created in the current activation frame, and when the function returns this frame is "deleted" from the stack.

Comment: the 2nd part will be dynamically allocatd and should be freed manually in the future.

Comment: @gfgqtmakia: No he should not. There is no concept of stack or frames in C++. The concept to learn here is scope.

Comment: @LokiAstari by activation frame I meant the current scope on the stack in which the function is operating, but you are also right - scope is the accurate definition because this situation can also occur in other scenarios :-)

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the second question: Yes, it will be dynamically allocated on the heap and needs to be `delete`d once you're done with it.

A silly question inbetween: What is the purpose of this code? You're passing the reference to a pointer...be sure NOT to change it, unless you want a memory leak. You may want to pass only the pointer (without the `&`, to alter the object, not the pointer to the object).

Regarding 'Returning by Value':

```
SoundFXSystem Engine::GetSystem(){
   SoundFXSystem system;           //Declares the local object
   sEngine->GetSystem(&system);    //Passes the pointer to the object
   return system;                  //Returns a 'Value Copy' of the object.
}
```

Comment: @Geotarget: `SoundFXSystem Engine::GetSystem(){ SoundFXSystem system; sEngine->getSystem( &system ); return system; }`.

Comment: @Angew `sEngine->GetSystem(&system);`. Combine that line with 'new', and you've got a reference to a pointer.

Answer (score 2):

This works but it's dangerous:

```
SoundFXSystem* Engine::GetSystem(){
    SoundFXSystem* system = new SoundFXSystem(); // var defined inside a function
    // ...
    return system; 
}
```

You are working with a raw pointer (`SoundFXSystem*`) and then, the compiler will not automatically destroy the object. You have to do it yourself by calling

```
delete p;
```

where `p` is a `SoundFXSystem*` with the same value as `system` set in `Engine::GetSystem()`. This is not straightforward as it seems due to possibility of exceptions being thrown. It's better to use a smart pointer (e.g. `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`):

```
std::shared_ptr<SoundFXSystem> Engine::GetSystem(){
    auto system = std::make_shared<SoundFXSystem>(); // var defined inside a function
    // ...
    return system; 
}
```

Comment: Never return pointers to dynamically allocated memory. There is no concept of ownership associated with a pointer and thus it leads to memory leaks. Any dynamic memory allocation should be wrapped in a containing object that controls lifespan (smart pointer usually).