# How to return a std::string.c_str()

Tags: c++, string, c++11, pointers, stdstring

I have a method which returns the constant char pointer. It makes use of a `std::string` and finally returns its `c_str()` char pointer.

```
const char * returnCharPtr()
{
    std::string someString;

    // Some processing!

    return someString.c_str();
}
```

I have got a report from [Coverity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coverity) tool that the above is not a good usage. I have googled and have found that the *char* pointer returned would be invalidated as soon as `someString` meets its destruction.

Given this, how does one fix this issue? How can I return a *char* pointer accurately?

Returning `std::string` would resolve this issue. But I want to know if there is any other means of doing this.

Comment: You can't return pointers to/of local objects. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3127507/1530508).

Comment: This sort of situation is a large part of the reason things like `std::string` was invented to start with. Almost anything you invent will nearly inevitably be either 1) a duplicate of what `std::string` already does, or 2) broken.

Comment: @Mr.C64 Removing the [C] tag changed the meaning of the question.  A C++/C interoperability question is VERY different from a C++ question, and would make returning a `const char*` far more valid.  Do you have a good justification for removing the [C] tag?

Comment: @user3210526 are you interoperating with C code?  If so, how is the lifetime of the returned `char*` managed in the C code?  If not, why tag your post with [C]?

Answer (score 26):

What happens in this code is:

```
const char * returnCharPtr()
{
    std::string someString("something");
    return someString.c_str();
}
```

1. instance of `std::string` is created - it is an object with automatic storage duration
2. pointer to the internal memory of this string is returned
3. object `someString` is destructed and the its internal memory is cleaned up
4. caller of this function receives ***dangling pointer*** (invalid pointer) which yields ***undefined behavior***

The best solution is to *return an object*:

```
std::string returnString()
{
    std::string someString("something");
    return someString;
}
```

When calling your function, **DO NOT** do this:

```
const char *returnedString = returnString().c_str();
```

because `returnedString` will still be dangling after the returned `std::string` is destructed. Instead store the entire `std::string`:

```
std::string returnedString = returnString();
// ... use returnedString.c_str() later ...
```

Comment: But why `const`? Now it can't be moved.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Well, it depends on how it's going to be used. But yeah, I admit that simple `std::string` will do better + it will be more flexible too.

Comment: I have a situation where returnString().c_str() == 0 (returned string is "m") but if I save the return value then call c_str() on the temp it works. Ideas?

Comment: 99% of the cases you should return std::string, but  the most voted answer should cover the case where char* is actually needed as return type (this is what the question asks anyway). Mr.C64 answer looks more complete to me.

Comment: What about the case when one would like to override the `what()` virtual function from `std::exception` , 
`virtual const char* what()const throw() override;`
if one would like to return anything that isn't a literal string, i.e returning some extra relavent run time information string, `char*` would be needed.
The only solution I seem to think about is making a static `std::string` and then `c_str()` wouldn't be returned as a dangling pointer, but it seems as a too ugly of a solution, and frankly I hate the idea of `static` life duration for a string that only needs to be printed once.

Comment: @Yuval cannot make it `static` because that won't be thread-safe. The canonical solution is to have a regular `std::string` in your exception class, fill it out, and return `c_str()` of that. It will stay alive as long as your exception object is, which is conforming to the `what()` interface.

Comment: Funny that you recommend what the OP explicitly does not want ;-)

Answer (score 18):

In C++, the simplest thing to do is to just return a `std::string` (which is also efficient thanks to optimizations like [RVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision#Return_value_optimization) and C++11 move semantics):

```
std::string returnSomeString()
{
    std::string someString;

    // some processing...

    return someString;
}
```

If you really need a raw C `char*` pointer, you can always call `.c_str()` on the returned value, e.g.

```
// void SomeLegacyFunction(const char * psz)

// .c_str() called on the returned string, to get the 'const char*'
SomeLegacyFunction( returnSomeString().c_str() );
```

If you really want to return a `char*` pointer from the function, you can *dynamically* allocate string memory on the heap (e.g. using `new[]`), and return a pointer to that:

```
// NOTE: The caller owns the returned pointer,
// and must free the string using delete[] !!!
const char* returnSomeString()
{
    std::string someString;

    // some processing...

    // Dynamically allocate memory for the returned string
    char* ptr = new char[someString.size() + 1]; // +1 for terminating NUL

    // Copy source string in dynamically allocated string buffer
    strcpy(ptr, someString.c_str());

    // Return the pointer to the dynamically allocated buffer
    return ptr;
}
```

An alternative is to provide a destination buffer pointer *and* the buffer size (to avoid buffer overruns!) as function parameters:

```
void returnSomeString(char* destination, size_t destinationSize)
{
    std::string someString;

    // some processing...

    // Copy string to destination buffer.
    // Use some safe string copy function to avoid buffer overruns.
    strcpy_s(destination, destinationSize, someString.c_str());
}
```

Comment: It is worth noting that the second example is probably not a very good idea. The caller is not going to expect that they have to delete that pointer and will most likely result in a memory leak.

Comment: @marsh It is the caller's responsibility to check if he owns the returned pointer.

Comment: @FabioTurati Thanks. Sure, I meant string size, not pointer.  Fixed.

Answer (score 9):

As this question is flagged C, do this:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <string.h>

const char * returnCharPtr()
{
  std::string someString;

  // some processing!.

  return strdup(someString.c_str()); /* Dynamically create a copy on the heap. */
}
```

Do not forget to `free()` what the function returned if of no use anymore.

Comment: I don't see the `C` flag, has it changed?

Comment: @Yakk: The original posting (http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/22330250/1) carried the C tag.

Comment: Thanks, I lost all my afternoon after a bug caused by something somewhat similar, but unfortunately more complicated. Anyway, thanks a lot.

Comment: @alk The caller has to free the memory is not a good idea. :(

Answer (score 5):

Well, COVERITY is correct. The reason your current approach will fail is because the instance of `std::string` you created inside the function will only be valid for as long as that function is running. Once your program leaves the function's scope, std::string's destructor will be called and that will be the end of your string.

But if what you want is a C-string, how about...

```
const char * returnCharPtr()
{
    std::string someString;

    // some processing!.

    char * new_string = new char[someString.length() + 1];

    std::strcpy(new:string, someString.c_str());

    return new_string;
}
```

But wait... that's almost exactly as returning a `std::string`, isn't it?

```
std::string returnCharPtr()
{
    std::string someString;

    // some processing!.

    return new_string;
}
```

<strike>This will copy your string to a new one outside of the function's scope. It works, but it does create a new copy of the string.</strike>

Thanks to Return Value Optimization, this won't create a copy (thanks for all corrections!).

So, another option is to pass the parameter as an argument, so you process your string in a function but don't create a new copy. :

```
void returnCharPtr(std::string & someString)
{
    // some processing!.
}
```

Or, again, if you want C-Strings, you need to watch out for the length of your string:

```
void returnCharPtr(char*& someString, int n) // a reference to pointer, params by ref
{
    // some processing!.
}
```

Comment: Don't return an rvalue reference. It has the same problem as an lvalue reference. (N)RVO takes care of expensive return copying even before C++11, and in C++11, the object will be moved out automatically if it can and (N)RVO doesn't work.

Comment: You just committed the same crime you accused the OP of! </joke> Rvalue references are still references, and returning one doesn't change the fact that it's still a reference to a local variable.

Comment: To add to what chris said, the code where you return an rvalue reference won't even compile as written, you need to `return move(new_string);` (and then you get to deal with a dangling reference). And your C-string example doesn't make sense at all; the function is taking a pointer to `const` when the intent is to operate on the input string? Also, that signature assumes the caller knows the length of the result.

Comment: Oh, my... I don't deserve to live D:
I got it all backwards!

Comment: 1 more correction: the length of new_string in your first example is 1 short (nul-terminator)

Comment: "This will copy your string to a new one outside of the function's scope. It works, but it does create a new copy of the string." -- no, that does not copy the string, it quite efficiently moves the string (actually, it doesn't even move it: the move is elided by the code, but that is a topic for a different post)

Comment: @ArthurChamz  Here `return CharPtr(char * someString, int n)` you really **cannot** return pointer as it is a local parameter and the pointer is a copy of passed value.
I suggest: `return CharPtr(char*& someString, int n)`

Answer (score 3):

The best way would be to return an `std::string`, which does automatic memory management for you. If, on the other hand, you were really into returning a `const char*` which points to some memory allocated by you from within `returnCharPtr`, then it'd have to be freed by someone else explicitly.

Stay with `std::string`.

Answer (score 3):

A solution which hasn't been evoked in the other answers.

In case your method is a member of a class, like so:

```
class A {
public:
    const char *method();
};
```

And if the class instance will live beyond the usefulness of the pointer, you can do:

```
class A {
public: 
    const char *method() {
        string ret = "abc";
        cache.push_back(std::move(ret));
        return cache.last().c_str();
    }
private:
    vector<string> cache; //std::deque would be more appropriate but is less known
}
```

That way the pointers will be valid up till `A`'s destruction.

If the function isn't part of a class, it still can use a class to store the data (like a `static` variable of the function or an external class instance that can be globally referenced, or even a `static` member of a class). Mechanisms can be done to delete data after some time, in order to not keep it forever.

Comment: Came here to add, essentially, this answer. To fix the cache size problem, make the cache a _fixed_ size and use it as a circular buffer. This can lead to surprises if the user nests function calls more deeply than the cache can handle, but that may be an acceptable documented restriction. I find a cache size of 8 to generally be sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

Your options are:

Return `std::string`

Pass a buffer to `returnCharPtr()` that will hold the new character buffer. This requires you to verify the provided buffer is large enough to hold the string.

Create a new `char` array inside `returnCharPtr()`, copy the buffer into the new one and return a pointer to that. This requires the caller to explicitly call `delete []` on something they didn't explicitly create with `new`, or immediately  place it into a smart pointer class.
This solution would be improved if you returned a smart pointer, but it really just makes more sense to return a `std::string` directly.

Choose the first one; return `std::string`.
It is by far the simplist and safest option.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `someString` is destroyed at the end of the function, and the function returns the pointer to non-existing data.

Don't return `.c_str()` of string that could be destroyed before you use the returned char pointer.

Instead of...

```
const char* function()
{
    std::string someString;
    // some processing!
    return someString.c_str();
}

//...

useCharPtr(function());
```

use

```
std::string function()
{
    std::string someString;
    // some processing!
    return someString;
}

//...

useCharPtr(function().c_str());
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have the freedom to change the return value of `returnCharPtr`, change it to `std::string`. That will be the cleanest method to return a string. If you can't, you need to allocate memory for the returned string, copy to it from `std::string` and return a pointer to the allocated memory. You also have to make sure that you delete the memory in the calling function. Since the caller will be responsible for deallocating memory, I would change the return value to `char*`.

```
char* returnCharPtr() 
{
    std::string someString;

    // some processing!.

    char* cp = new char[someString.length()+1];
    strcpy(cp, someString.c_str());
    return cp;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass in a pointer to your string, and have the method manipulate it directly (i.e., avoiding returns altogether)

```
void returnCharPtr(char* someString)
{    
    // some processing!
    if(someString[0] == 'A')
       someString++;
}
```

Comment: This assumes the caller knows how long the string is going to be, which is most often not the case.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem when implementing https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/exception/what `what()` virtual function of `std::exception` offspring.

Well the signature must be

```
virtual const char* what() const throw();
```

This means however that returning `std::string` is not an option unless you want to rewrite standard library. I would like to know what these people saying "always return `std::string`" would think about standard library developers...

To allocate dynamic array is not a good idea in exception handling. I end up with the following solution. The whole `class` will be just wrapper for the final message that could not be modified even inside constructor.

```
class KCTException : public exception 
{ 
    const char* file;
    const int line;
    const char* function;      
    const std::string msg;
    const std::string returnedMessage;
    
public:
    KCTException(std::string& msg, const char* file, int line, const char* function) 
        : file(file)
        , line(line)
        , function(function)
        , msg(msg)
        , returnedMessage(io::xprintf("KCTException in [%s@%s:%d]: %s", function, file, line, msg.c_str()))
    {
    }
    
    const char* get_file() const { return file; }
    int get_line() const { return line; }
    const char* get_function() const { return function; }
    const std::string& get_msg() const { return msg; } 
    const char* what() const throw()
    {
        return returnedMessage.c_str(); 
    }
};
```

Here `io::xprintf` is my wrapper function that behaves as `printf` but returns string. I found no such function in a standard library.

Comment: Returning by `const` value almost never makes sense. You should return by const reference, or at least by non-const value (to allow move semantics).

Comment: I have to implement this method from standard library https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/exception/exception/what/ and thus I can nor really choose its return type.

Comment: Returning a const pointer is fine. I was talking about `const std::string get_msg()`.

Comment: Thank you, I have eddied the answer and changed it in my repository accordingly. Returning const object by non const value would probably produce compiler warning/error and I just wanted a quick fix, but const reference is obviously better solution.

Comment: *"Returning const object by non const value would probably produce compiler warning/error"* No, it's perfectly fine and recommended.