# How to convert? C-string format of toString()

Tags: c++, c-strings

I need a c-string format of toString(), but how do I convert it? Here is the function:

```
string toString(){
    string tmp;

    char buf[80];
    if (*d != 1)
        sprintf_s(buf, "%d/%d", *n, *d);
    else sprintf_s(buf, "%d", *n);
    tmp = string(buf);

    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: Where do `n` and `d` come from?

Comment: sorry to not mention, private: int *n, *d.

Comment: So this is a method of some existing class. Might help to see enough of the class to understand the structure. Also, the goal itself is a bit unclear. Is this the function you're trying to write? Or are you trying to write a separate function that returns a C-style string? Or use this function and then convert to C-style string?

Comment: I suppose there's a few cases where C's sprintf has some advantages over C++'s stringstream, but this is most definitely not one of those cases.

Comment: Since this is C++, you could also do `return (*d != 1) ? std::to_string(*n) + "/" + std::to_string(*d) : std::to_string(*n);` provided that this is what you want.

Comment: If you don't mind the asking, why pointers to `int`s? Not much in the way of savings there and private doesn't give pointers much in the way of encapsulation

Answer (score 1):

> need a c-string format of toString()

If you just need to convert the output of toString(), you can use

```
const char* s = toString().c_str();
```

Note that `c_str` simply returns a pointer to the underlying character storage of the string. So you do need to be careful to not get a pointer to the string and then having that string go out of scope, in which case the pointer may or may not still point to valid memory. Your function currently is returning a `string` (I'm guessing your code has `using namespace std`) which means a *C++ string object*.

If you don't absolutely need C strings, I would recommend using C++ strings, since they are more current and just easier to work with. However, if for reasons somewhere else in the code you *do* need a C string, your function should look like

```
char* toString() {
    // formatting your output
}
```

Because all a C string is is a null terminated (`'\0'`) array of `char`, and an array is equivalent to a pointer to the first element, so that's where `char*` comes from.

Because of that, something needs to “own” the memory of that character array, and that something needs to have a “lifetime” that is at least as long as the scope you need it for. If you make a function that returns a raw `char *` you should make sure that the pointer is to either a:

- static string literal
- a dynamically allocated string with the `new` operator that you then make sure to `delete` later.

In either case, C++ stringstreams could make formatting your output far more intuitive. You will need `#include <sstream>` and then some googling will steer you in the right direction. This solution *also* works if you need a C string, because C++ strings have a method called `c_str()` that converts C++ strings into C strings (null terminated array of characters):

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

string toString() {
    stringstream ss; // these are so useful!
    if (*d != 1) {
        // this probably isn't the exact formatting you are looking for,
        // but stringstreams can certainly do it if you research a bit!
        ss << *n << *d;
    }
    else {
        ss << *n;
    }
    return ss.str();
}

void function_that_needs_c_string(const char * c);

int main() {
    function_that_needs_c_string(toString().c_str());
}
```

Comment: Should be `const char* s = toString().c_str();`

Comment: `const char* s = toString().c_str();` is dangerous since the value that you are pointing to in the underlying `const char*` value goes out of scope by the time you use `s` - see details in answer of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22330250/how-to-return-a-stdstring-c-str

Comment: Yes you are correct. I have learned some things since I wrote this answer. I will edit.

Comment: I would outright remove this line of code, and demonstrate something like `foo(toString().c_str())`, which is safe.